# porque el archivo txt no se crea? C++

Tags: c++, txt

estoy desarrollando un programa en C++ que me registre empleados y que los datos queden guardados en un archivo .txt para cuando vuelva a abrir el programa. he definido dos ofstream, uno que me cree un archivo txt que guarde la fecha y otro que me guarde los datos de los empleados pero el problema es que al compilar no me salta ningún error pero no me crea el archivo txt para los datos del empleado y el de la fecha si.

difinicion de los fstream:

```
ofstream entrada;
ifstream salida;
```

esta es la función para guardar los datos de los empleados:

```
void guardardatosarchi()
{
    entrada.open("registro.txt",ios::out|ios::trunc);
    if (entrada.fail())
    {
        cout<< "ERROR AL ABRIR EL ARCHIVO"<<endl;
        Sleep(1500);
    }
    else
    {
        for(int fila=0;fila<4;fila++)
        {
            for(int columna=0;columna<4;columna++)
            {
                if(piso4[fila][columna].cubiculo==1)
                {
                    entrada<<piso4[fila][columna].Documento<<" "
                //  <<piso4[fila][columna].doc<<" "
                    <<piso4[fila][columna].nombre<<" "
                    <<piso4[fila][columna].apellido<<" "
                    <<piso4[fila][columna].fila<<" "
                    <<piso4[fila][columna].columna<<" "
                    <<piso4[fila][columna].direccion<<" "
                    <<piso4[fila][columna].numDoc<<" "
                    <<piso4[fila][columna].eps<<" "
                    <<piso4[fila][columna].nacimiento.anio<<" "
                    <<piso4[fila][columna].cargo<<" "
                    <<piso4[fila][columna].llamados_at<<" "
                    <<piso4[fila][columna].sexo<<" "
                    <<piso4[fila][columna].telefono<<" "
                    <<piso4[fila][columna].ult_evaluacion_lab<<" "
                    <<piso4[fila][columna].cubiculo<<" "
                    <<piso4[fila][columna].piso<<" "
                    <<z<<endl;
                }               
            }
        }
        for(int fila=0;fila<4;fila++)
        {
            for(int columna=0;columna<4;columna++)
            {
                if(piso3[fila][columna].cubiculo==1)
                {
                    entrada<<piso3[fila][columna].Documento<<" "
                //  <<piso3[fila][columna].doc<<" "
                    <<piso3[fila][columna].nombre<<" "
                    <<piso3[fila][columna].apellido<<" "
                    <<piso3[fila][columna].fila<<" "
                    <<piso3[fila][columna].columna<<" "
                    <<piso3[fila][columna].direccion<<" "
                    <<piso3[fila][columna].numDoc<<" "
                    <<piso3[fila][columna].eps<<" "
                    <<piso3[fila][columna].nacimiento.anio<<" "
                    <<piso3[fila][columna].cargo<<" "
                    <<piso3[fila][columna].llamados_at<<" "
                    <<piso3[fila][columna].sexo<<" "
                    <<piso3[fila][columna].telefono<<" "
                    <<piso3[fila][columna].ult_evaluacion_lab<<" "
                    <<piso3[fila][columna].cubiculo<<" "
                    <<piso3[fila][columna].piso<<" "
                    <<z<<endl;
                }
            }
        } 
        for(int fila=0;fila<4;fila++)
        {
            for(int columna=0;columna<4;columna++)
            {
                if(piso2[fila][columna].cubiculo==1)
                {
                    entrada<<piso2[fila][columna].Documento<<" "
                //  <<piso2[fila][columna].doc<<" "
                    <<piso2[fila][columna].nombre<<" "
                    <<piso2[fila][columna].apellido<<" "
                    <<piso2[fila][columna].fila<<" "
                    <<piso2[fila][columna].columna<<" "
                    <<piso2[fila][columna].direccion<<" "
                    <<piso2[fila][columna].numDoc<<" "
                    <<piso2[fila][columna].eps<<" "
                    <<piso2[fila][columna].nacimiento.anio<<" "
                    <<piso2[fila][columna].cargo<<" "
                    <<piso2[fila][columna].llamados_at<<" "
                    <<piso2[fila][columna].sexo<<" "
                    <<piso2[fila][columna].telefono<<" "
                    <<piso2[fila][columna].ult_evaluacion_lab<<" "
                    <<piso2[fila][columna].cubiculo<<" "
                    <<piso2[fila][columna].piso<<" "
                    <<z<<endl;
                }
            }
        } 
        for(int fila=0;fila<4;fila++)
        {
            for(int columna=0;columna<4;columna++)
            {
                if(piso1[fila][columna].cubiculo==1)
                {
                    entrada<<piso1[fila][columna].Documento<<" "
                //  <<piso1[fila][columna].doc<<" "
                    <<piso1[fila][columna].nombre<<" "
                    <<piso1[fila][columna].apellido<<" "
                    <<piso1[fila][columna].fila<<" "
                    <<piso1[fila][columna].columna<<" "
                    <<piso1[fila][columna].direccion<<" "
                    <<piso1[fila][columna].numDoc<<" "
                    <<piso1[fila][columna].eps<<" "
                    <<piso1[fila][columna].nacimiento.anio<<" "
                    <<piso1[fila][columna].cargo<<" "
                    <<piso1[fila][columna].llamados_at<<" "
                    <<piso1[fila][columna].sexo<<" "
                    <<piso1[fila][columna].telefono<<" "
                    <<piso1[fila][columna].ult_evaluacion_lab<<" "
                    <<piso1[fila][columna].cubiculo<<" "
                    <<piso1[fila][columna].piso<<" "
                    <<z<<endl;
                }
            }
        }   
        entrada.close();
        cout<<"DATOS GUARDADOS"<<endl;
    }   
    menuprincipal();   
}
```